# Timephased view of Remaining work in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

How to get a time-phased task-wise view of 'remaining work' in MS Project?
Have tried the task usage option but the timephased view seems to be available only for the total work, and not the remaining work.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to show time-phased *remaining work* in the task usage view of Microsoft Project, unfortunately.

If you are savvy vba, you can write a macro that can get time-phased remaining work by taking the time-phased total work and subtracting the time-phased actual work. [I've written some sample code to do this for a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70026316/vba-extracting-from-ms-project-remaining-work-by-assignment-by-week/70047040#70047040)

If you aren't savvy with vba, I know of at least [one third party add-in](https://ssitools.com/ssi-time-scaled-values/) to MS Project that can give you the capability to do this (and other features). It isn't free though.